# Zapier Formatter - Hashtags Words In A String With Exemptions

Tags: string, automation, zapier, formatter

I am looking to automate my social-media hashtags in **Zapier**, dependent on the post title.

**Input:**  High School English As A Second Language Teacher

**Output:**  #High #School #English #Second #Language #Teacher

I found the Regex (I think), which is \b(\w) to select the first letter of each word. However, this may not be Python. I would need exceptions too, to remove words like "A", "As", "The" etc.

Answer (score 0):

While this is possible, it becomes very tricky and error prone once there's any punctuation or other characters. Nevertheless, here's a simple first pass:

```py
import re
title = input_data['title']
# 'High School English As A Second Language Teacher'

words = re.findall(r'\w{3,}', title) 
# ['High', 'School', 'English', 'Second', 'Language', 'Teacher']

result = ' '.join(['#' + word for word in words])
# '#High #School #English #Second #Language #Teacher'

return {'result': result}
```

That finds all words that are 3 or more characters, adds a `#` to each, and joins them all into a big string. You can play with that regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/A3FL9G/1).

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you for taking the time to answer this question! It looks like you've thought about it a great deal.

Have a great weekend :)